# Twilio Complications

Tags: twilio, thingworx

I'm currently trying to use Twilio with my Thingworx platform to send sms messages when a sensor becomes triggered.

When I set the sensor to an active triggered state, the sms messages then spam me and do not turn off until i set it to a false manually.

Is there a script that can turn a twilio sms to false, or a reason why it is spamming me?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share the code that you're using to do that? My guess is that you are checking the sensor as part of a loop and just sending every time, but I can help better if you can show me that code.

Comment: @Rachel, did you ever sort this out? Would be awesome if you could share the code snippet and/or your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The code sending sms should look something like this:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient 

# put your own credentials here 
ACCOUNT_SID = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
AUTH_TOKEN = "your_auth_token" 

client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN) 

client.messages.create(
    to="+15558675309", 
    from_="+15017250604", 
    body="This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?", 
    media_url="https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2899/14341091933_1e92e62d12_b.jpg", 
)
```

It is likely as Phil stated above, that you were checking the sensor as part of a loop and just sending every time.